# Is MySQL and Python a good choice to build a desktop application?

Tags: python, mysql, desktop-application, inventory

I am new to desktop applications and Python and the idea of this application simply to keep track of items of in an inventory. The user will be able to CRUD the data, make reports, etc.

Is it ok to use MySQL locally for this application? I know a couple of options, but I am not quite sure what to do.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can use whatever works. Why MySql in particular? Python comes with `SQLite` [builtin](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html).

Comment: I personally am finding `sqlite` to be super easy to work with in python.

Comment: In retrospective, 4 years later, so much was learned... Thanks everyone for the answers and sorry for my lack of responsiveness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah! it would be great if you use MySQL and Python. That wil do help to understand how RDBMS works. Once you are done with that, you can even work with [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) (light weight DBMS & NoSQL) and [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/) (if you are curious to work with Document Oriented DB / NoSQL)

If you want you can refer [Basic Python & MySQL Example 1](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_database_access.htm), [Basic Python & MySQL Example 2](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlpython/), [Tuts for SQLite](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/) and [Tuts for MongoDB](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/)